# Transformer humming after replacing halogen bulbs with LEDs

Tags: transformer, led-driver

I replaced the IKEA 10W G4 halogen bulbs in my under-cabinet lights with 1.5W G4 disc LEDs and the 120-12V AC transformer started buzzing, but not if I kept one halogen bulb in. I recall reading somewhere (but can't find the link), IIRC, it's because the transformer is designed for a resistive load and the LEDs are a capacitive (?) load, and they aren't drawing enough power.

- if I put a resistor across one of the terminals (the power supply has 6 of which 3 are free), will it stop the buzzing? If so, how many ohms?
- can I just replace it with a 12V DC power supply without worrying about polarity if the LEDs are 12V AC/DC?

Thanks!

Comment: It cannot be computed and must be done by trial and error. Perhaps a 6W Halogen or 3W Xmas Light is adequate or a 10 W resistor derated 50% to run at 80'C  then V^2/R=Pd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely it’s because the LEDs don’t behave the way halogens do.  Halogen lamps are more or less resistive so the current increases more or less linearly with voltage on each mains half-cycle, so the loading varies gently.  The LEDs will draw almost no current while the voltage is low (below about 12V but will then start to draw current relatively abruptly towards the peak of each mains half-cycle.  It’s probably this that’s causing the transformer to hum, and there will be harmonics well into the audible range so it will be more noticeable than just a 50Hz hum.  The load is much less than a halogen lamp, so adding just one halogen makes this abrupt change far less apparent.

Comment: So can I replace the AC transformer with a DC one without worrying about polarity if the LEDs are marked AC/DC or do I have get the polarity right? The wires aren't marked.

Comment: Essentially yes, AC LEDs will incorporate a rectifier so should be fine to run on DC regardless of the polarity.  They may be a little fussy about the voltage though, 12VAC peaks at around 17V and the LEDs may struggle to illuminate fully at 12VDC.  If you have long wires and a number of LEDs you may find that the brightness drops significantly along the length, increasing the voltage a little would resolve this.  You may find that the LEDs illuminate somewhat below 12V though and it won’t be a problem.

Comment: They're wired in parallel, would it be fine to drive them through a 18V 65W laptop charger? It's right near my gas outlet, I don't want to create a fire hazard!

Comment: The laptop charger's voltage is somewhat on the high side, but it could work.

Comment: I just used that as an example because that's what I've got, but I could get one around15-16V too. Thanks for your help, everybody!

Answer (score 2):

> can I just replace it with a 12V DC power supply without worrying about polarity if the LEDs are 12V AC/DC?

Yes.

LED lamps rated 12V AC/DC would have an internal bridge rectifier.

[image]

They would work equally well with a 12 V transformer or a 12 V DC power supply.

You could use a 12V DC power supply without worrying about the polarity.